# metaphone 3 implementation with java

Tags: java, metaphone

Does anyone know where the code (not commercial stuff) can be found for Metaphone 3 matching for java? Even though apache has implemented Metaphone 1.2 (please see this site: [Apache Metaphone 1.2 Implementation](http://commons.apache.org/codec/)). But it didn't implement Metaphone 3. Any help is huge for me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>The author decided not to release nor the algorithm nor its source for the third version of Metaphone.</strike> [Metaphone 3 is sold as source code] You can contact the author via [his website](http://www.amorphics.com/) to see if some special cases are taken into account.

But you won't find anything legal freely available, sorry

Answer (score 2):

Metaphone 3 is sold as C++, Java, or C# source.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is too late for the OP but for anyone else looking for a java implementation of Metaphone3 check out the [github repo of openrefine](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/blob/master/main/src/com/google/refine/clustering/binning/Metaphone3.java).

PS I know this is a "bad" link only answer but the source code is pretty large, so lets hope github is not shutting down the next years :-)

Comment: This is interesting how closed-source software got part of an open-source software and actually - got published.